# Первый запуск приложения после установки длится 30 секунд

Tags: android, загрузка

После установки первый запуск приложения длится около 30 секунд, при повторном запуске такой проблемы нет! В проекте использовалось:

1. SQlite
2. multidex=true
3. sharedPreferencies....

в чем может быть причина ??

Comment: Включите StrictMode http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html и добавьте  к вопросу логи, снятые при первом старте

Comment: Скорее всего дело в создании БД. Попробуйте в начале метода её создания и в конце измерить прошедшее время выводом оного в логи.

Comment: в StartActivity не создаётся БД

Answer (score 1):

Причина была "Android studio 2.0"... после сборки буилда при помощи Android studio предыдущей версии проблема испарилась !